Display My Custom Product Attributes in WooCommerce Long Description
I am trying to automatically display product attributes at the end of the long description but my code makes it appear in the short description. How would I adjust this to come either as a tab by itself or in the long description?
The code is working perfectly in terms of showing the attributes on the product but the placement is wrong.


/* Vis alle produkt attributter på vareside */

function njengah_woo_attribute(){
 
    global $product;
 
    $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
 
    if ( ! $attributes ) {
 
        return;
 
    }
 
    $display_result = '';
 
 
    foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {
 
        if ( $attribute->get_variation() ) {
            continue;
        }
 
        $name = $attribute->get_name();
 
        if ( $attribute->is_taxonomy() ) {
 
            $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product->get_id(), $name, 'all' );
 
            $njengahtax = $terms[0]->taxonomy;
 
            $njengah_object_taxonomy = get_taxonomy($njengahtax);
 
            if ( isset ($njengah_object_taxonomy->labels->singular_name) ) {
 
                $tax_label = $njengah_object_taxonomy->labels->singular_name;
 
            } elseif ( isset( $njengah_object_taxonomy->label ) ) {
 
                $tax_label = $njengah_object_taxonomy->label;
 
                if ( 0 === strpos( $tax_label, 'Product ' ) ) {
 
                    $tax_label = substr( $tax_label, 8 );
 
                }
 
            }
 
            $display_result .= $tax_label . ': ';
 
            $tax_terms = array();
 
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
 
                $single_term = esc_html( $term->name );
 
                array_push( $tax_terms, $single_term );
 
            }
 
            $display_result .= implode(', ', $tax_terms) .  '<br />';
 
 
 
 
        } else {
 
            $display_result .= $name . ': ';
 
            $display_result .= esc_html( implode( ', ', $attribute->get_options() ) ) . '<br />';
 
        }
 
    }
 
    echo $display_result;
 
}
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'njengah_woo_attribute', 25);



